# Accessing sub class static attributes from superclass method

Tags: java, abstract-class

I will give a quick example since is not that complicated when viewed in that way. The output below example will be null:

```
abstract class SuperClass { // it doesn't need to be abstract but that's my case now
    // needs to be static
    static String var_name = null;
    void method(){
        System.out.println(var_name);
    }
}
class subclass{
    // needs to be static
    static String var_name = "I need to print this"
    void otherUnrelatedMethod(){
        method(); // calling method() here gives me null
    }
}
```

I'm aware of two options to achieve what I want:

I can easily achieve this just by passing var_name as a parameter on method(), which is the option I'm using right now.

Also I can override method(), but doing that would bring a lot more work since there is a lot of subclasses and method() is actually pretty big.

Is there any other option besides these two? I.e.: If I could maybe use bounding with a subclass type `<S extends SuperClass>` to get de desirable effect. Or even using reflection, although I heard it can make the program quite slow

Comment: Could you make another method `getVarName()` that would return `var_name`, and then override that method in the subclass?

Comment: @Progman I dont't know... Maybe? I was expecting something with reflection or bounding with sublcass type. I think I will just close this since this Java inflexibility is angering me atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice pattern for this kind of problem:

```
abstract class SuperClass { 
    String var_name() {
        return null;
    }

    void method() {
        System.out.println(this.var_name());
    }
}

class subclass extends SuperClass {
    @Override
    String var_name() {
        return "I need to print this";
    }

    void otherUnrelatedMethod() {
        method(); 
    }
}
```

- First, super class has no information about sub classes. This means that you cannot call sub class function from super class.
- Second, `static` members exist in `class`, not in instance. It is impossible but if one sub class overrides any super class static member, other sub classes will be victims.

You would better use function that returns `var_name` and `@Override` it from sub classes.

Comment: Sorry, the function is not static...

Comment: Yea, I noticed as soon as I tried to compile your solution. The problem is that I'm using this value for static methods too. I'm gonna edit my post to clarify.

Comment: @JãoSchmidt I edited my answer as well. `static` is not for what you want to do.